# Young's modulus from MD simulation

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, coarse-grained

I have a coarse-grained model of a surface which is almost planar/flat in 2D. Now, I want to compute some of its mechanical properties to test it. Young's modulus is one of the properties that come to my mind. So, conceptually, is it doable in GROMACS?

I think, I can keep one end of the surface fixed with position restraint, and the other end is linked to a spring, and is pulled at a constant velocity (Steered Molecular Dynamics), and with elongation, I may be able to compute the Young's Modulus. Is it a correct way of doing, though I don't know its limitations? Any suggestions, if there are other methods available as well. Thanks.

Comment: In this method, there can be limitations like - what is the spring constant I need to use, or the velocity of pulling.

Comment: How did this go? Have you found anything new that might be helpful, in the last 5+ months? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.